# Logging in database

Tags: java

im doing a application in java and i need to do the logs, i heard about log4j, and the log api  already inside, but first of all i thought about doing it inside a database like a normal statement for example:

btnPress =

```
{
dosomething/something with the database, when button pressed

String time = year + month + date + hour + minutes + seconds;
LogFunction("Message for the Log", time, user, screen)
}


public void LogFunction(String msg, String time String user, String screen) {

insert statement to insert into a specific table: time, user, msg, screen;
}
```

explaination:

a column of ordernumber(auto increase) will be the primarykey

Time: column will be different every time and the ID for searching specific log

user: column the user that generated the log

msg: column what happened and need to be logged

maybe in include something more to log

the question is:

This is Stupid, wrong, dont make sense or its a good way for doing the log?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question. You *may* log to a DB. You *may* log to a file. Which makes the "most" sense depends entirely upon your needs, how you need to analyze those event, what tools you may use to analyze those events, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton, i mean, doing in this way, its not wrong/stupid? ofc i just need to make the log if the other thing happen with full success, if not just log the error, and a smart way to access the log for each movement/change isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

note that log4j support logging to database as well, you dont have to write any code yourself, check out `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender` at the following [example](http://www.cubrid.org/store_java_logs_to_databdase_using_log4j)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to write *clear* logging, to maximize the information value (and help for debugging) of what you get.

- Log meaningful information, don't just dump data
- When to log:  Requests, Decisions, Outcomes plus any External Integrations
- Log *before* activities, and *after* decisions
- What to log:  Key facts only
- Log identifiers, not detail

http://literatejava.com/logging/logging-the-most-effective-debugging-tool/

I recommend logging to a text file, as it's faster & cheaper.. unless you really need transaction-safe & long-term storage of your logs. Obviously it depends on requirements, but text files are normal.